# running r script and get output log in real time in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to run r script and get output log in real time in shiny.

My code like this.
This is just my thinking that can be run.
But, the problems is that printing log output in shiny app is not in real time.
Just when finished the r script, then out log has appeared in shiny app.
I want to get out log in real time in shiny app.
Anybody knows what is the problems and what should I do for my intention.

```
ui <- fluidPage(    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            ### Input1
            textInput("input1", "input1:"),
            ### Input2
            textInput("input2", "input2:"),
            ### 
            actionButton("run", "Running", width='200px')
        ),
        mainPanel(
            verbatimTextOutput('log')
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$run, {
      ### clear log file
      system("> log_path/test.log")
      ### excute run text
      runs <- paste("Rscript 'script_path/test.R'",
                    input$input1,
                    input$input2,
                    ">> 'log_path/test.log' 2>&1")
      system(runs)
    })

    output$log <- renderText({
      ### 1sec refresh
      invalidateLater(1000, session)
      ### read log file 40 tail
      text_log <- readLines("log_path/test.log",  n = -1) %>% 
          tail(40) %>% paste(collapse = "\n")
      return(text_log)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to see output log after pressing the `actionButton`?

Comment: yes, streaming output log after actionButton.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass `wait = FALSE` into `system` function.

With `system(runs, wait = F)` everything works.